# Admin login forbbiden 403 csrf verification on django 1.2.5

Tags: python, django

i know this have been asked already but i still can't get the answer to it.

When i try to log in on django admin, (just created an app and straigh to admin, without modifications) and in google chrome it doesnt allow me to log in, instead it pops up this error.

just to add, if i log in on admin in chrome by incognito tab it works! and i can log in.

also i can log in on internet Explorer last version, so it means that it is happening on my regular google chrome windows, what can i do??

i tried many solutions and noone gave to the answer but interstingly some of the solutions let the app work, with like no other effect.

this is my setting app:
    INSTALLED_APPS = [

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

i know i can ignore it for now but i feel it will bring a lot of problems later on if i dont find out whats going on, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, it should not ask for 403 csrf verification. Could you please check if there is any JS error or any browser plugin/addon trying to change the crsf_token hidden field value.

Comment: yes i already tried and it did not work either, i think i have to modify the form code in admin, i will try it

Comment: can you upload somewhere so I can check?